# Model X is not associated with Model Y cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have Image which belongsTo User, and I have Coupon which belongsTo User.  Each of the images and coupons table have a foreignKey of 'user_id' in my db.  When I debug the output of this controller logic:

```
$f=$this->Coupon->find('all', array(

            'conditions'=>array(
                'OR'=> array (
                    'Coupon.expires' =>0,
                    'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('y-m-d')
                    )
                ),
            'contain'=>array(
                'Image',
                'Location'=>array('id','address','city','state','zip','area_code','exchange','sln','website'),
                'User'=>array('id')
                )
            )

       );
      $this->set('printcoupons', $f);
      }
```

I get all of my data except an Image array, which cake tells me is not associated with Coupon.  I have tried setting the recursiveness of Coupon to 2, and I get no change in what gets retrieved.  I tried loading the User model and doing a find that way, with disastrous results.  I just don't understand how better to get Image and Coupon to play together, considering I don't want them directly associated with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way you have your 'contain' array would imply that Image is directly associated with Coupon (no model between them) which isn't the case. The coupon belongsTo User and User has* Image. So the Image would need to go in the User array. All the models that you contain can use all or most of the find() options available. when using contain, recursive is boolean.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options

I think you should really just add this to your AppModel since you pretty much always use contain and **Containable must to be attached to all models used in containment**

`public $actsAs = array('Containable');`

That way you don't have to keep attaching the behavior to every model.

```
    $f = $this->Coupon->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Coupon.expires' => 0,
                    'Coupon.end_date >' => date('y-m-d')
                )
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Location' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'id', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'area_code',
                        'exchange', 'sln', 'website'
                    )
                ),
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                    'Image'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: I attached containable to the model, and I plugged in the 'Image' into the 'User' arrray.  The only way it showed in debug was if I removed 'fields'=>array('id').  Now, the problem is that I don't know how to access it.  Normally I'd do something like echo $c['Image']['logo'] but cake says this is an undefined index.  I hav e tried in my view foreach($coupondata as $value) { foreach($value['Image'] as $v) { echo $v['logo']; }} but that doesn't work.  Neither does $value['User']['Image']----that was me grasping at straws by the way.